# gradlewAssemble generating the same APK over and over

Tags: android, build, react-native

I'm currently experiencing an issue with the build process of an android app using react native.

Running the command :

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

is generating a new APK but the js bundle seems to be the same all the time. As a result none of app updated are being included in the build. On top of that, when running the app in the simulator using :

```
react-native run-android
```

updates the app ok in the simulator. Assuming it's a cache issue, I ran the below each time before trying to generate a new APK :

```
rm -rf /android/build 
rm -rf /android/app/build 
rm -rf /android/.gradle
```

but still getting the exact same version of JS in the output APK.

Is the bundle cached somewhere? How can I solve the issue and update the code in my APK?

Thanks!

Comment: Try deleting the app from the device and installing again?  Maybe it's cached on the device..

Comment: hey rooftop - I have tried that already, still experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cleaning before assemble solved this for me:

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```